# KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE (stack overflow) in libobjc dealloc

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, stack-overflow

I recently received a crash report that looks like this:

`0   libobjc.A.dylib  0x0000000193dfea88 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 0
1   libobjc.A.dylib  0x0000000193e0bf34 objc_destructInstance + 88
2   libobjc.A.dylib  0x0000000193e0bf8c object_dispose + 24
3   My App           0x00000001000d88fc -[CCAction dealloc] + 44
4   My App           0x00000001000e6bf8 -[CCActionSequence .cxx_destruct] + 36
5   libobjc.A.dylib  0x0000000193dfeb18 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 144
6   libobjc.A.dylib  0x0000000193e0bf34 objc_destructInstance + 88
7   libobjc.A.dylib  0x0000000193e0bf8c object_dispose + 24
8   My App           0x00000001000d88fc -[CCAction dealloc] + 44
9   My App           0x00000001000e6bf8 -[CCActionSequence .cxx_destruct] + 36
10  libobjc.A.dylib  0x0000000193dfeb18 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 144
11  libobjc.A.dylib  0x0000000193e0bf34 objc_destructInstance + 88
12  libobjc.A.dylib  0x0000000193e0bf8c object_dispose + 24
13  My App           0x00000001000d88fc -[CCAction dealloc] + 44
14  My App           0x00000001000e6bf8 -[CCActionSequence .cxx_destruct] + 36`

...and it continues on like this forever. Some kind of infinite recursion happening in `dealloc` that is causing a stack overflow.

There are only 2 method calls that are visible to me and one of them is `.cxx_destruct` which is an internal private method used by ARC. The other is the `dealloc` method of `CCAction` which only has a log statement in it:

`-(void) dealloc {
    CCLOGINFO(@"cocos2d: deallocing %@", self);
}`

The crash is really hard to reproduce; I've only seen it once. However my app has not been released to the public yet so I'd really like to figure out what is causing it. Any help debugging this would be greatly appreciated.

I am using `Cocos2D 3.3.0` and `iOS 8.1`

Comment: This may not be a recursion, but the wash-out of an infinitely long ActionSequence ... causing a stack overflow of all things. Check out your sequences, where you 'compute' them (probably in a loop), and try to see if any one of these could recurse or loop infinitely for some unforeseen condition in your program's state.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ARC, sending messages to `self` in `dealloc` doesn't work like how it used to in manual memory management. ARC does all of the cleanup/disposing in `.cxx_destruct` BEFORE calling `dealloc`, so sending messages to `self` in `dealloc` will cause undefined behavior - most probably crashes. Unlike in manual memory management where you can send messages to `self` in `dealloc` before calling `[super dealloc]`.

From your code, it looks like `CCLogInfo` is sending a message to `self`, most probably `[self description]` (assuming `CCLogInfo` parameters are just a format string with arguments). This will cause a crash, but I'm not sure why it is causing recursion - can you share the code to `CCLogInfo`?

Comment: You are correct in that `CCLOGINFO` is using `self` as a format string argument, so the `description` message is being sent. However this crash report is from a release build, and thus the macro translates to `do {} while (0)`.

Comment: Do you have a link to any more discussion on ARC disposing of objects *before* calling `-dealloc`?

Comment: hi @Greg, i can see where the misunderstanding is coming from - it is clarified in the last line of the first paragraph in my answer - when ARC is enabled, your 'dealloc' is called after 'release', but before [super dealloc]. [see the dealloc section of the clang docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#dealloc)

(sorry for deleting the previous comment, i was digging the sources but found the documentation more straightforward)

Comment: Cool, thanks. It looks like the clang docs don't actually forbid calling methods on `self` from `-dealloc`, which is too bad.